# Chrome Extension: How to use an image in CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How do I use an image in CSS? I looked up older threads of StackOverflow and the official documentation but could not find anything to help me. Why is it so hard to use an image?

This is how I use the image in CSS:

```css
    background-image: url('chrome-extension://gkiofiinipjoiemamkbdhonmljhagnce/images/arrows-up-blue.png');
```

Directory structure:

```
coolextension:
---manifest.json
---images
------arrows-up-blue.png
...
```

Manifest:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Reading time",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Add the reading time to Chrome Extension documentation articles",
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
          "resources": ["images/arrows-up-blue.png"],
          "matches": ["https://www.cooldomain.de/*"]
        }
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "css": ["styles/content.css"],
          "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
          "matches": [
            "https://www.cooldomain.de/*"
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The error:

[image: Image of the error]

Can someone help me?

Comment: So long as your url patterns are correct in web_accessible_resources, that would 100% work. However, you have hardcoded the chrome extension URL which does change for various reasons when building an extension locally. The first thing Id check is going to background.JS and running ```chrome.runtime.getURL()``` to make sure gkio is the correct url. (I noticed there are logs where its saying another chrome extension url that starts with bmnl, so if that's yours, then this is definitely the problem.

Comment: replace the id with `__MSG_@@extension_id__`, also don't forget to reload the extension.

Comment: Replacing the id with `__MSG_@@extension_id__` did not work. It resolved to my package id interestingly though when I inspected it in dev tools.